# Google Sheets formula query an array based on matches from another array

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, textjoin

I would like to filter/query Columns A:B based on 1 or more values in Column E.

Essentially, I want to Return values from ColB for any values within ColA which appear in ColE.  I wish I could use this:

```
=query({$B$1:$C$101},"select Col2 where Col1='" & {$E$2:$E$101} & "'")
```

But, using an array {$E$2:$E$101} for the values to match doesn't work within a query. Here is a link to my spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fUixRqqOYh6LleMkvgJdmp7yg2YqOnfzjuHB3glMBKY/edit?usp=sharing

[image: picture of a spreadsheet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

formula should be:

```
=QUERY({B:C}, "select Col2 where Col1 matches '^"&TEXTJOIN("$|^", 1, E:E)&"$'", 0)
```

[image: 0]